# How to find documents with child collection containing only certain value

Tags: mongodb, querydsl

I have a following JSON structure:

```
    {
        "id": "5cea8bde0c80ee2af9590e7b",
        "name": "Sofitel",
        "pricePerNight": 88,
        "address": {
            "city": "Rome",
            "country": "Italy"
        },
        "reviews": [
            {
                "userName": "John",
                "rating": 10,
                "approved": true
            },
            {
                "userName": "Marry",
                "rating": 7,
                "approved": true
            }
        ]
    }
```

I want to find a list of similar documents where ALL ratings values of a review meet a certain criteria eg. less than 8. The document above wouldn't qualify as on of the review has rating 10.

with Querydsl in the following form I still obtain that documnt

```
BooleanExpression filterByRating = qHotel.reviews.any().rating.lt(8);
```

Comment: If you are seeking for the documents that has not any rate greater than 8 then this query can do that `db.qHotel.find({"reviews.rating":{"$not":{"$gt":8}}}`. But are you sure that you don't want to calculate the average rating?

Comment: @Rancbar This is not what I was looking for. I don't want to use the native mongodb query. The qHotel is an automatically generated class from the querydsl framework. It offers type-safe, java-based fluent api querying framework. Anyway, the query you have provided was missing the closing parenthesis for the `find()` method. I have fixed it and executed with a proper collection name and it did not returned any results.

Comment: @Rancbar Btw, `reviews` is a collection of review elements, each having it's own rating. Logically, the path would look like reviews.review.rating. I've tried it, too, but no success either.

Comment: The `reviews` is not a collection or even a document. It is just a part of a document. The document is this whole JSON. And the collection is the place that there can be many of these documents. `reviews` just an Array element containing Objects.

Comment: This query should work. you can test it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sw8Q5yy54OB)

Comment: @Rancbar by saying "reviews is a collection of review elements" I didn't mean that it is a separate mongo collection nor is a separate document. I used the word collection exchangeably for array as a child element of the main document. The query works indeed, I forgot to switch to the right db in the CLI. Nevertheless, if a document has no reviews, it will also be included.

Comment: Yes, I get that. You are right.

Comment: this would be the query that meets the requirements:
`db.collection.find({
  $and: [
    {
      $where: "this.reviews.length > 0"
    },
    {
      "reviews.rating": {
        "$not": {
          "$gte": 8
        }
      }
    }
  ]
})`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$filter` and `$match` to filter out the transactions that you don't need. Following query should do it:

**Note**: The `cond` in the $filter is the opposite of your criteria. Since you need `ratings` *less than 8*, in this case you gonna need `ratings` *greater than or equals 8*

```
db.qHotel.aggregate([
{
    $addFields: {
        tempReviews: {
            $filter: {
                input: "$reviews",
                as: "review",
                cond: { $gte: [ "$$review.rating", 8 ] } // Opposite of < 8, which is >= 8
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    $match : {
        tempReviews : [] // This will exclude the documents for which there is at least one review with review.rating >= 8
    }
}
]);
```

The result in the end will contain empty field named `tempReviews`, you can just use `$project` to remove it.

**EDIT**:

Check the example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Dt8daE7y6G9).

Comment: I am searching for a querydsl based solution. I tried it anyway and it didn't work. I thought the double $$review was the problem but after correcting it the query still didn't work

Comment: I don't know what you mean it doesn't work. Check here: it works as you've mentioned in the question: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Dt8daE7y6G9

Comment: You are right, the query works, I must have messed up with something. Still, this is not the QueryDsl approach so I cannot accept it as an answer.